# Sonarlint-core hook points for new grammar

Tags: sonarqube

I am doing a POC where I am trying to write grammar/creating a new analyser.
I am able to run the grammar using the sonar-qube and sonar-scanner.
Now,I need to integrate the same with sonar-lint eclipse plugin.

I have git copied the sonarlint-eclipse code and found that it is internally using sonarlint core to load the jars of different grammars like Java,Javascript using helper classes like PluginRepository.

I have found that at below path `C:\Users\xyzUser\runtime-EclipseApplication\.sonarlint\storage\localhost\global`, "plugin_references.pb" file contains the key,hash and jar name.

Can somebody please explain the exact hook points to introduce new grammar jar for sonar-lint eclipse plugin?
I am trying to run it in both Standalone mode and Connected Mode.

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to run your new grammar in SonarLint; it maintains a whitelist of plugins it will run. Inevitably, yours is not on it.

Comment: I believe this would be 2nd step. First the grammar jar has to be set in plugin_references.pb? By default eclipse sonar-lint plugin is creating this file. What do you suggest?There is 1 .proto file in sonar-lint core module.Do I have to use it to generate the new plugin_references.pb file?